# How to generically type a function that returns a value array of an object array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type a function that returns an array of values of a generic object array (used for getting all column values of a table).

```
class DataSource<T> {
  
  constructor(private data: T[]) {}

  public getColumnValues(column: keyof T): any[] { // this is the thing I don't know how to type!
    return data.map(entry => entry[key]);
  }
}
```

The goal is having a generic signature that shows the correct return value. For example: `getColumnValues('someDate')`  should be  `Date[]` or `getColumnValues('someString')` as  `string[]`

I tried searching for this but I probably couldn't phrase my question properly...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make `getColumnValues` a generic function so that the type can be based on the specific property and not just any property of `T`.  We will return an array of the properties for that key. `K` is the key, `T[K]` is the value, and `T[K][]` is the array of values.

```
class DataSource<T> {
  
  constructor(private data: T[]) {}

  public getColumnValues<K extends keyof T>(column: K): T[K][] {
    return this.data.map(entry => entry[column]);
  }
}
```

Typescript is able to infer `K` when you call the function so it will return the right type.

```
const mySource = new DataSource([{id: 1, name: "John"}, {id: 2, name: "Susan"}]);

const names = mySource.getColumnValues('name'); // type is string[]

const ids = mySource.getColumnValues('id'); // type is number[]
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mA7jkw)